# how to split a line by a point which is on the line but not in the linestring itself?

Tags: point, postgis-2.0, linestring

i need some help with the following:

```
i have a linestring - geom
i have $lat,$lon (using some php syntax)
```

- i have an osm table with the roads geom, i am trying to get closest point, and then split the road into two parts, by that closest point.

after using the lat,lon and st_closestpoint to retrieve the closest point on that line.
the point which will be returned is not necessarily exist in the original linestring points.

```
ST_ClosestPoint (geom_way, ST_SetSRID (ST_MakePoint($lon, $lat), 4326)  ) as closest_point
```

after that i would like to split the geom(linestring) into two lines by closest_point,
and this is where i need help.

i tried using

```
 st_asgeojson (ST_Split (geom_way, ST_ClosestPoint (geom_way, ST_SetSRID (ST_MakePoint($lon, $lat), 4326)  )))
```

but i believe that because the point i use is not on the geom, its not spliting and always returns the entire geom.

if i use a point which exist in the line string, it works well.(but not what i need)

how can i solve this? any solution even if with totally different approach will do.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

aha! i found the solution:

use:

```
ST_Line_Locate_Point(geom_way,closest_point)
```

to fetch the portion of the line and then can use the following to split it correctly:

```
ST_Line_Substring (geom_way,0,ST_Line_Locate_Point(geom_way,closest_point)) as first_half
ST_Line_Substring (geom_way,ST_Line_Locate_Point(geom_way,closest_point),1) as other_half
```